# latex beamer footnotemark color

Tags: latex, beamer

I have a presentation where the title slide has a black background so text colors have been set to white. The author names have to have superscript number corresponding to a footnote listing their institution. The footnotemark is note white. How can I make it white.

Comment: I think you should ask this on http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways...

1) Using \author + \institute + \maketitle commands

This is pretty easy. You just want to do this:

```
% First define your author and institute (taken from Beamer manual example)
\author[Hemaspaandra et al.]{L. Hemaspaandra\inst{1} \and T. Tantau\inst{2}}
\institute[Universities of Rochester and Berlin]{
\inst{1}Department of Computer Science\\
University of Rochester
\and
\inst{2}Fakult\"at f\"ur Elektrotechnik und Informatik\\
Technical University of Berlin

% Now make the actual title slide
\frame[plain]{
  \setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=white}
  \maketitle
}
```

2) If you're manually placing the author and institute:

First, *don't* use \author and \institute, just use \title{Presentation Title}. Then try something like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\maketitle  % will insert the title alone

\begin{center}

  \setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=white} % setting the footnote color to white
  John Doe\footnote{Institute Name 1 }

  Jane Doe\footnote{Institute Name 2 }

\end{center}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=default} % now set back to normal future frames
\end{frame}
```

Way #1 is going to look more like regular beamer, so if using the \institute command was what you were going for, do it that way. #2 is just another way and also shows you the syntax for setting individual colors of elements.
    \setbeamercolor{elementName}{fg=color}
See the [Beamer Manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) Chapter 17 for most of this stuff. Good luck!